# Dynamically autowire a bean without using ApplicationContext.getBean() in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a servlet that does validation on XML files based on the address of the person contained in it. The validation is specific to each state, so I have several implementations of my validator, but I don't know which one to use until the request is parsed each time.

I am using Spring, and right now I am getting the correct validator with the following:

```
Validator validator = applicationContext.getBean(this.state + "Validator");
```

This seems to break some of the inversion of control. I thought about moving this to a factory class that essentially does the same thing, but abstracts it to a factory:

```
@Component
public class ValidatorFactory {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Validator getValidator(String state) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(state + "Validator");
    }
}
```

It seems like there should be a better way to get the correct bean at runtime without using getBean(). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Map :

```
@Component
public class ValidatorFactory {

    @Autowired
    Map<String,Validator> validators;

    public Validator getValidator(String state) {
        return validators.get(state + "Validator");
    }
}
```

You can pre-populate the map with the required beans throughs Spring.

Comment: If my Validator is a prototype bean, would Spring generate a new one every time I got one from the Map?

Comment: @LucasP I don't understand why a validator should be a prototype bean instead of a singleton one. Anyways, the answer to your question is no. The map is just a map; Spring populates it with all different implementations of the `Validator` interface or abstract class, using the bean name as the key.

Comment: @Magnamag I was using an example that was easy to type up and understand what I was asking. In the actual code, it is less of a validator and more of a "make sure it is valid" by changing it as necessary. There are dependencies on other injected beans that are either prototype or request scope.